# glossaries-extra - wrong spacing around math relation

Tags: spacing, glossaries-extra

When I use a relation in math mode with the glossaries package, the output looks exactly the same as if typed directly. However, when using glossaries-extra, the spacing is incorrect. What can be the reason?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{eq}{name={eq},
symbol={=},
description={Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum.}}

\begin{document}
$ \alpha = \beta $

$ \alpha \glssymbol{eq} \beta $
\end{document}
```

[image]

When I comment the `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}` line, the spacing is correct:

[image]

Comment: glossaries does a lot stuff when processing \glssymbol and  this hides the \mathrel. I'm not really surprised, more that it works with glossaries alone.

Comment: wrapping a relation in braces makes it behave like an ordinary character with no spacing around it.  try `symbol={{}={}}` to force the spacing.  (answering in a comment because i can't test.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've tried that and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation from Barabara Beeton solved the problem: the solution is to change the symbol definition from `symbol={=}` to `symbol={{}={}}` Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{eq}{name={eq},
symbol={{}={}},
description={Quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum.}}

\begin{document}
$ \alpha = \beta $

$ \alpha \glssymbol{eq} \beta $
\end{document}
```

Comment: A drawback of this solution reveals when you want something like $\alpha\glssymbol{eq}_s \beta$.